# Help. Getting exception executing PostMethod.getStatusCode()!

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-commons-httpclient

Couldn't figure out why I'm getting Null pointer here : System.out.println(method.getStatusCode()); !?
method initialized and successfully executed!
Any ideas?
Sample code here. I'm using commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

```
            PostMethod = new PostMethod(url);

        LogInHelper.logRequest(httpClient, method);

        try {
            httpClient.executeMethod(method);
            method.getResponseBodyAsString();
        } catch (HttpException e) {
            LOG.error("@getSessionId() error connecting to " + url, e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error("@getSessionId() error connecting to " + url, e);

        }

        LogInHelper.logResponse(method);

        System.out.println(method.getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning and recompile whole project helped in this case.

Comment: Hi. It's too bad nobody reply to your question. I just have the same problem as you. The problem is I always clean and recompile the project every morning. And the problem persisted. I look up on the internet and there's no people with the same problem like this.